Kanya-daana vs Kanya aadaana
Recently I came across someone saying the process of bestowing the daughter, which is normally called as Kanya-daana (gift of Kanya) is wrong but it is Kanya-aadaana (acceptance of Kanya).
Looking for scriptural evidence (ideally, with Samskrita shlokas/mantras) to "daana" vs "aadaana". My gut feel is daana is correct as I have many places its mentioned that giving away kanya results in merits (hence, its a gift); but will be glad if proved wrong and aadaana is correct term.

Kanyā-dāna is the correct word as per the scriptures. Below is an excerpt from the Skanda Purana.

īśvara uvāca |
sarveṣāmeva dānānāṃ kanyādānaṃ viśiṣyate |
yo dadyātparayā bhaktyābhigamya tanayāṃ nijām || 30 ||

kulīnāya surūpāya guṇajñāya manīṣiṇe |
sulagne sumuhūrte ca dadyātkanyāmalaṃkṛtām || 31 ||

aśvānnā gāṃśca vāsāṃsi yo'tra dadyātsvaśaktitaḥ |
tasya vāso bhavettatra padaṃ yatra nirāmayam || 32 ||

Of all Dānas, Kanyā Dāna (gift of a virgin) is the best. A parent
should give his daughter after approaching a boy of noble birth,
handsome features, learning and discretion. The father should give his
well-adorned daughter on an auspicious Lagna and Muhūrta. If he offers
horses, elephants and garments in accordance with his capacity, his
stay shall be in the region where there is no ailment.

Related:
Another proof of kanya-dana
Dowry is not kanya-dana
